# Vanished question about cars and copyrights/trademarks

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I remember quite well that someone with a music-related name had asked a question about cars and photos - and now [almost the same question - even referencing the same site as origin of photos - appeared.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59782/can-i-use-photos-of-cars-in-promotional-material-if-the-photos-come-from-unsplas) As I tried to link it at dupe, the original - which was made around Christmas - appears gone.

Was the original question I noticed (and remember to have answers) deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was lost to an unfortunate scenario that is presently [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312594/241697):

1. [The question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/59420/10) was closed (as off-topic due to request for specific legal advice).
2. Before it was closed the question received two answers.
3. The user who posted the question self-deleted.

Conditions #1 and #3 trigger deletion of the question ... *unless* the question has *upvoted* answers.  Neither of the answers had yet been upvoted, so they got deleted too.

I thought that unfair to the answerers so I undeleted the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks. That explains where the bounty question about children watching pornography in Maryland went